# Creating a quote in Postmates - duration and pickup_duration fields

Tags: quote, postmates

When we create a quote for delivery in Postmates, the response returns 2 params:
duration and pickup_duration.

Does duration include pickup_duration or duration is delivery estimation only for the route from the store to the customer and doesn't include the time to get to the store?

Thank you